Add Random seed slider to a node group to affect other input values randomly
I Hope someone can help me with that, can't find any solution fewwww
I'm trying to integrate a random seed slider to my nodegroup!
Basically I would love that slider to change randomly all the other sliders values within their respective ranges.
I've tried it this way but its to tricky/not elegant nor optimised.

I've tried to play with drivers but my knowledge is limited and I encountered limitation because even tho the randomise script expression worked, if you want to adjust the value manually its still changing randomly the value.
For example random driver seed give a 45.003 but I want to reach 46.2, if I slide manually to that value it changes the value randomly again.
Maybe I was close to something this way or maybe by python scripting its possible?
I've heard that the python script can be embeded in the nodegroup so that would be perfect since I want to share the nodegroup, people wont have to run any script or install anything...
Do anyone know how to achieve such a thing?
Big thanks in advance for any help

Hello. Are you aware of the Map Range node ? The White Noise node outputs a random value between 0 and 1.

You can setup your node group like so and chain value and white noise nodes. Add a different input seed for each value. If you really want to prevent having seeds that look alike use big values for the different white noise addends.



thanks so much, I've tried that in the first place and still the best solution.
Thanks for your help :D

You cannot embed an arbitrary python code inside node groups. Drivers can be used for that but the auto execution must be enabled. And it is not really portable.
I recommend you to implement next behaviors: controlled and random. Then add a global seed input and a factor input to mix between the controlled and random values internally.
The global seed would be used to seed all the internally generated random values so the result would be deterministic and also can be used as an input point for a further per object or UV island randomization.
The factor is used for switching between the behaviors or mixing-in a random deviation to the user input.

Totally, thank you for confirming the obvious. I thought it was possible but its not.
Thanks a lot!!
